# Scheduling due to the last execution of the parallel region

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I needs some help with scheduling of a parallel region. My setup is as follow, I have a parallel region over a few (less than 10 say) expensive independent functions:

```
    for (j=0; j < 1000; j++) {
        //Parallel region
        #pragma parallel for
        for (i=0; i < number_of_functions; i++) {
            fcn(j,i) //Expensive
        }
        //Serial region (must be so)
        ...
    }
```

The time it takes to evaluate fcn is highly dependent of i and not so much on j.

Consider the example with three expensive functions and two threads, where the functions take approximately:

First iteration on j:

```
fcn(j=0, i=1) ~ 10s
fcn(j=0, i=2) ~ 10s
fcn(j=0, i=3) ~ 100s
```

Second iteration on j:

```
fcn(j=1, i=1) ~ 10s
fcn(j=1, i=2) ~ 10s
fcn(j=1, i=3) ~ 100s
```

So here I'd like to schedule i=3 first and then the rest. So what I'd like is that the scheduling is done due to the iterations that took the longest in the last jth iteration.

I know about the scheduling options for the for loop (static, dynamic) and the closest that would fit would be dynamic with a chunksize of one. Although in my example it wouldn't help as i=3 would always be evaluated last (if we have two threads). So my question is if there is an automatic way of scheduling due to the last execution of the parallel region? Or do I have to manually time the different evaluations and do the scheduling on my own?

Consider a second example

First iteration on j:

```
fcn(j=0, i=1) ~ 10s
fcn(j=0, i=2) ~ 10s
fcn(j=0, i=3) ~ 100s
fcn(j=0, i=4) ~ 10s
fcn(j=0, i=5) ~ 50s
```

Second iteration on j:

```
fcn(j=1, i=1) ~ 10s
fcn(j=1, i=2) ~ 10s
fcn(j=1, i=3) ~ 100s
fcn(j=1, i=4) ~ 10s
fcn(j=1, i=5) ~ 50s
```

Here I'd like to schedule i=3 first and i=5 second. I know that in the first iteration there is not much to do but the second iteration, there I'd like the last iteration to be taken into account for the scheduling.

I hope I made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just loop backwards from 3 down to 1 in combination with `schedule(dynamic,1)`?

Comment: For the first case, yes that would work. But I don't know that that would be the case in general, i=0 could just as well be the call that took the longest. I added a second example which is a bit more difficult.

Comment: You need something like a priority task queue - first you push all tasks (i.e. sets of parameters to invoke `fcn()` with) with priorities based on the their compute weight and then let the pool of threads pull from the head of the queue and make the calls. OpenMP does not provide such a scheduling construct. Moreover, its scheduler is blind and cannot be supplied with priority/weight information. You should probably check a different paradigm, e.g. Intel Threading Building Blocks (a.k.a. TBB).